# HttpRequestMessage Content Disposed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient, .net-4.7.2

For better logging and tracing, we have created an extension method, which is inside we are doing something:

```
if (!httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    ResponseError error = new ResponseError();
    error.Message = $"Error response status code reported: {(int)httpResponseMessage.StatusCode} - {httpResponseMessage.ReasonPhrase}";
    error.AbsoluteUri = httpResponseMessage.RequestMessage?.RequestUri?.AbsoluteUri;

    if (httpResponseMessage.RequestMessage?.Content != null)
    {
        // here we are getting an ObjectDisposedException, Object name: System.Net.Http.StringContent
        error.RequestContent = await httpResponseMessage.RequestMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }

    if (httpResponseMessage.Content != null)
    {
        error.ResponseContent = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }

    throw new HttpRequestException(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(error));
}
```

So, in failing scenarios, request message content being disposed of, I do not know why.

Using:

- .NET Framework 4.7.2
- httpRuntime 4.5
- System.Net.Http.httpClient

**Exception:** `ObjectDisposedException, Object name: System.Net.Http.StringContent`

**UPDATE:**

The response content is not being disposed of. Only request message content is disposed of.

**UPDATE2:**

We are not facing this issue with our .NET Core API's problem only with .NET Framework Services

Comment: I would totally expect the request content to be gone by  the time you're dealing with the response. It is not contractual to hold on to the content longer then needed. If you want the content captured for logging later, capture it before it is being send-off. Imagine scenario's where GigaBytes are being sent. That hurts memory pressure very much if it is required to keep the request content around.

Comment: Maybe you are right, but request content is not be disposed of with .net core services

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the `HttpContent` as a Stream.
So, once you read it, you need to seek it back to the 0th position to be able to re-read it.

```
//Before sending it 
await request.Content.LoadIntoBufferAsync();

//Sending out the request

//After receiving the response
var stream = await request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); //OR stream.Position = 0;

var requestBody = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks for your time! if you look at my code, only `System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage` is available for us. Anyway, I hardcoded and  tried with your suggestion, still getting `ObjectDisposedException`

Comment: @Maruf If you can access only the response, then I'm unaware of any working solution.